# How to Setup/Configure nginx server for dotnet project (csproj)?

Tags: .net, apache, nginx, csproj, visual-studio-mac

I am new to dotnet and with nginx. I have moved my dontnet project on Mac (Visual studio mac preview), so in mac i dont have ISS.

So, trying ISS alternative like **nginx** or **apache**.

**Need info - How to Setup/Configure nginx server for dotnet project (csproj) on Mac machine?**

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run **ASP.NET Core** on Mac with an HTTP server like [Kestrel](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer) and use nginx as reverse proxy for static content.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app-xplat/start-mvc

For console apps see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/using-on-macos

Hope this helps